# eula help on terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I was using terminal for idle3:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

but, this purple, black, and gray EULA screen came on, I wasn't able to click out of it, and the python IDLE never installed? Anyone know what happened?

Comment: While the EULA screen is showing in the terminal, you should be able to jump to the OK button (or similar) by pressing TAB a few times. When the button is selected, you could press Enter to accept. You can verify if `idle3` was installed by running `dpkg -l idle3`, you should see a line starting with `ii idle3` if the package is installed. If it wasn't, or it's not in a usable state, then reinstall it.